# Calling new class and send data to construct

Tags: php, oop

Well the title says it all. I have a problem with calling classes dynamic. My head controller is getting an array with all the components that needs to be loaded. 
This is my code

```
public function generateViews($views) {
    $this->getView('header');
    $this->getView('footer');
    //echo $this->header;
    foreach ($views as $components) {
        include_once "Application/" . $components['folder'] . $components['name'] . "/" . $components['name'] . "_Controller.php";
        $this->{$components['name']} = new $components['name'];
        //echo $this->{$components['name']}->view;
    }
    //echo $this->footer;
}
```

the problem is my function calls new classes in the foreach. But i can't give the classes data to the construct.  `$this->{$components['name']} = new $components['name']($extradata, true, false);`

Is there any way to give data to the construct without calling the classes hardcoded?

Comment: First approach might be to use a factory pattern instead of directly instantiating the objects, second is to simply copy the class name to a scalar variable and then use `new $component(...);''.

Comment: use factory design pattern

Comment: Why can't you pass arguments to the class? [Works just fine.](https://3v4l.org/KnisD)

Comment: @arkascha thanks mate. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Well i have a solution.

```
$item = $components['name']';
$this->{$components['name']} = new $item(true,false);
```